how to process a sequence of items N at a time
I want to run a command N times in parallel using bash and xargs on a Linux system. The command is:
for i in `seq 1 $(howmany.txt)`; do aprogramm --file file$i.dat ; done

The file howmany.txt contains the value 100 and ntimes.txt contains the value 5.
The files file1 to file100 exist, in sequence from 1 to 100, and I want to process them 5 at a time in parallel. How do I do this with xargs?

So you want to run aprogramm --file file1.dat file2.dat file3.dat file4.dat file5.dat etc., or something else?

No, i want to run aprogramm --file file1.dat + aprogramm --file file2.dat + aprogramm --file file3.dat + aprogramm --file file4.dat + aprogramm --file file5.dat and if than any from this 5 commands done with the job, than i want to run aprogramm --file file6.dat and so on, up to 100

when you're clarifying your requirements, please make the change in the body of your question to avoid unnecessary trails of ever growing comments. Please .

are you sure it is $(howmany.txt) and not $(cat howmany.txt) ??

@OlivierDulac: In Bash $(< howmany.txt) is the more efficient way to do it.

@PeterCordes : I see you have the luxury of "recent" (aka, not 20+ years old) bash ^^ not all servers have it

To process the files in batches, use xargs -n. If a single file is processed per batch, use 1:
echo file*.dat | xargs -n1

To process then in parallel, use -P.
echo file*.dat | xargs -n1 -P$(< ntimes.txt) aprogramm --file


How can i do this instead of echo file1.dat with seq 1 $(howmany.txt) ? at other places in mycommand, i need only the number, not a full filename. and how to add the number at two places in mycommand? something like this: aprogramm --file file$i.dat mountpoint$i

seq 1 $(< howmany.txt) | sed 's/^/file/;s/$/.dat/' | xargs ...

Or printf file%d.dat $(seq 1 $(< howmany.txt)) | xargs ...

i do test: seq 1 $(< howmany.txt) | xargs -n1 -P$(< ntimes.txt) echo $i $i . the output is: 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 .... why? why not: 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 .... . in howmany.txt is 20 in ntimes.txt is 5 at this moment, i can not check are 5 jobs run parallel. but what i do not  understand, how to become my output that i want?!

There's no $i in xargs. You can use -I to introduce a name for the argument, though: xargs -n1 -I% -P5 echo % % %

There are quite a few issues with what you show. First, $(howmany.txt) will try to execute howmany.txt. If that is an executable script, stored in your PATH, which prints out a number, then it might work, but if it is just a text file with a number, you would want $(cat howmany.txt). Second, it is better (clearer and allows nesting commands) to use $( command ) instead of `seq`command.
That said, to do this with xargs, you would want something like:
seq 1 $(< howmany.txt) | xargs -I {} -n1 -P $(< ntimes.txt) aprogramm --file file{}.dat

Bu really, this is a job for GNU parallel:
parallel -j ntimes.txt aprogramm --file file{} < howmany.txt

Or, if all your files are named fileN and you want to process all fileN (so you don't really need the howmany.txt), then you could do:
parallel -j ntimes.txt aprogramm --file {} ::: file*

One of the many advantages parallel has over xargs is that you can change the number in howmany.txt while this is running, to be able to increase or decrease the number of running jobs.

In Bash as least, $(< howmany.txt) expands to the file contents without needing to actually exec cat, and maybe without even forking; I didn't check.  (This question is tagged bash so I didn't try to check if it's portable to POSIX sh either.)

@PeterCordes yes, and it's more elegant, no question. But I had written this answer before choroba had posted theirs (I had it as a draft, but hadn't finished so I hadn't posted it) and since I had written mine with cat as I hadn't thought of using $(< file) and it's already mentioned in another answer, I figured I'd leave it be. But fair enough, I might as well include it.

I'd partly read most of the answers but hadn't noticed that.  Glad you decide to edit this.  I did notice markp-fuso's read -r max   < howmany.txt into a shell variable.

Eh, it also turned out I had the file names completely wrong so I really needed to edit!

Instead of writing a script to do the commands, write a script that echoes the commands:
for i in `seq 1 $(cat howmany.txt)`
  do echo "aprogramm --file file$i.dat"
done

Each line of that output should be valid command syntax for whichever shell you use.
Once that output looks good, pipe it to parallel(1)with the -j5 option to run 5 jobs in parallel:
for i in `seq 1 $(howmany.txt)`
  do echo "aprogramm --file file$i.dat"
done | parallel -j5


are you sure it is $(howmany.txt) and not $(cat howmany.txt) ??

@OlivierDulac As sure as the OP is. :) Edited.

Assumptions:

files howmany.txt and ntimes.txt are guaranteed to contain a single integer and nothing else
there may be other files in the directory we do not want to process (eg, a simple find . -name 'file*.dat' could return more files than desired)

For demo purposes:
$ cat aprogram
#!/bin/bash

echo "input: $@"
sleep 3

$ cat howmany.txt
10

$ cat ntimes.txt
4

One idea using Jim's method to print a list of file names piped to xargs`:
read -r max   < howmany.txt
read -r count < ntimes.txt

for ((i=1; i<=max; i++))
do
    echo "file$i.dat"
done | xargs -r -n1 -P "$count" ./aprogram --file

This generates:
input: --file file1.dat        # 4 invocations in quick succession
input: --file file2.dat
input: --file file3.dat
input: --file file4.dat
                               # 3 sec delay
input: --file file5.dat        # 4 invocations in quick succession
input: --file file6.dat
input: --file file7.dat
input: --file file8.dat
                               # 3 sec delay
input: --file file9.dat        # last 2 invocations in quick succession
input: --file file10.dat
                               # 3 sec delay


I recently had to solve this without using xargs/parallel....
NUM_THREADS=5

for i in $( sequence_generation ) ; do
    while [ "$NUM_THREADS" -le "$( jobs  | grep 'Running' | wc -l)" ]; do
        sleep 1
    done
    {
        slow_thing $i 
    } &
done
while [ 1 -le "$( jobs  | grep 'Running' | wc -l)" ]; do
   sleep 1
done


Nice! A couple of nitpicks/suggestions: avoid CAPS variables and you can use grep -c to avoid the need for wc -l. Yeah, OK, more nitpicks than suggestions, really.

Good point about grep -c - OTOH variable capitalizaiton should follow the context where the code is implemented - and I consider it good practice to put configurations in global scope variables/use CAPITALS for global scope. Hence capitals for NUM_THREADS and lower case for i
